# While loop not working at all

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ready = input('Are you ready to start the quiz? [Y/N]: ')

if ready == "N":

    quiz()

else:
    questionsasked = []
    qnum = random.randint(1,5)
    questionsasked.append((qnum))
    while (qnum)not in(questionsasked):
```

So the main issue is that my program won't continue after I enter "Y", it just stops in the shell with no errors at all.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's calling quiz() if the user enters N ?

Comment: this is just part of the code, the "N" part works fine.(it restarts the whole program). But the else part doesn't work at all, it's to do with the while loop

Comment: well your code is incomplete, so .... how could we help?

Comment: You know that you are just appending `qnum` to `questionsasked` and right after that your loop runs while `qnum` IS NOT IN `questionsasked`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` condition is false, so your program ends.

```
questionsasked = []
qnum = random.randint(1,5)
questionsasked.append((qnum))            # added qnum to questionsasked
while (qnum)not in(questionsasked):      # qnum is in questionsasked, so condition is false.
    ...
```